# how to pause and unpause video transmission using Android Pjsua 2?

Tags: java, android, sip, pjsip, pjsua2

I wish to pause and unpause video transmission in video call on fly without dropping Audio call using Android Pjsua2 library. But some how i am not able to understand how to implement that feature to sample android pjsua2 app. Any help would be highly appreciated.

i went through below documentation and not able to understand ..how to implement it

> enum pjsua_call_vid_strm_op This enumeration represents video stream
> operation on a call.
>
> PJSUA_CALL_VID_STRM_START_TRANSMIT     Start transmitting video stream.
> This will cause previously stopped stream to start transmitting again.
> Note that no re-INVITE/UPDATE is to be transmitted to remote since
> this operation only operates on local stream.
>
> PJSUA_CALL_VID_STRM_STOP_TRANSMIT      Stop transmitting video stream.
> This will cause the stream to be paused in TX direction, causing it to
> stop sending any video packets. No re-INVITE/UPDATE is to be
> transmitted to remote with this operation.

link [documentation](https://www.pjsip.org/docs/2.2.1/pjsip/docs/html/group__PJSUA__LIB__CALL.htm#ga8a7b29df0618360407b8aae888421a36)

Answer (score 1):

Consider this code:

```
fun strmStopTransmit() {
    if (manager.isCaptureActive(camDevId)) {
        val callVidPrm = CallVidSetStreamParam()
        callVidPrm.setCapDev(camDevId)
        call.vidSetStream(pjsua_call_vid_strm_op.PJSUA_CALL_VID_STRM_STOP_TRANSMIT, callVidPrm)
    }
}
```

Where `manager` is instance of `pj::VidDevManager` ([link](https://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/classpj_1_1VidDevManager.htm)) (you can get it from `pj::Endpoint` ([link](https://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/classpj_1_1Endpoint.htm))) and `call` is instance of `pj::Call` ([link](https://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/classpj_1_1Call.htm)).

The implementation of the inverse function (resuming transmission) is obvious.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Daszuone, how can i get the device id of camera -- in your case camDevId

Comment: VidDevManager has a getDevInfo function. You can iterate through all cameras (eg. in for loop 0 to getDevCount from manager) and grab the id's of devices you need.

Comment: can you please elaborate with code example of getting device id .  getDevCount() gives only number of device and getDefInfo require device id .. ?

Answer (score 0):

This document is too lengthy and not proper. I have been went through the same problem.

The following might help you:

```
SipManager.getInstance()?.activeCalls?.get(callId)?.mVideoPreview?.stop()
```

Here, **activeCalls** is instance of **MyCall**.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    CallInfo ci = currentCall.getInfo();
    CallMediaInfoVector callMediaInfoVector = ci.getMedia();
    for (int i = 0; i < callMediaInfoVector.size(); i++) {
        CallMediaInfo callMediaInfo = callMediaInfoVector.get(i);
        if (ep.vidDevManager().isCaptureActive(callMediaInfo.getVideoCapDev())) {
            CallVidSetStreamParam callVidPrm = new CallVidSetStreamParam();
            callVidPrm.setCapDev(callMediaInfo.getVideoCapDev());
            try {
                if(!isVideoDisable){
                    currentCall.vidSetStream(pjsua_call_vid_strm_op.PJSUA_CALL_VID_STRM_STOP_TRANSMIT, callVidPrm);
                    isVideoDisable = true;
                }else {
                    currentCall.vidSetStream(pjsua_call_vid_strm_op.PJSUA_CALL_VID_STRM_START_TRANSMIT, callVidPrm);
                    isVideoDisable = false;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                cLogE(TAG,"exception");
            }
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    cLogE(TAG,"exception");
}
```