# Is there any registration Listener for Pjsip pjsua2 (Android )?

Tags: android, pjsip, pjsua2

I have been going through Android `Pjsip` `pjsua2` sample app. It works but they didn't implemented registration listener. And couldn't find any good enough documentation as well. Eg for android native sip stack, they have registration listener for registration failure, registration success as well. Please help me with a sample code as well if its possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're talking about empty brackets beside notifyRegState at files sample.java and sample2.java in pjsip-apps sources. You can easily implement your own registration listener there.

```
public void notifyRegState(pjsip_status_code code, String reason, int expiration) {}
```

All you have to do, is to check the values of arguments in this method. Most important is first argument (`code`) - compare it's value with status you want to check from `pjsip_status_code` enumeration ([link](https://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/group__PJSIP__MSG__LINE.htm)), and perform some action proper for your needs. Explanation of SIP response codes can be found i.e here ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SIP_response_codes)). Second argument (`reason`) is description (reason phrase) of received status. The last one (`expiration`) is interval to next SIP registration (another words - validity time of current registration).

If this is not helpful for you, tell something more about your problem.

Comment: it would be great help , if you could tell any idea about  toggling audio and video call during the call with just a button click

Comment: What do you mean? You want to change a/v device? Or switch between multiple calls?

Comment: i just want to disable and enable video during a call . eg when i click a disable video button , i can only have voice call

Comment: Read here [link](https://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/classpj_1_1Call.htm) : vidSetStream and PJSUA_CALL_VID_STRM_STOP_TRANSMIT operation.

Comment: hi @DaszuOne  : i went through those link already , but i find it really complex and hard to follow them , can you please help me with some example at here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63702759/how-to-pause-and-unpause-video-transmission-using-android-pjsua-2/63721612#63721612

Answer (score 0):

Create a class which extends Call and inside that press ctrl+o search for notifyRegState()

```
public class MyVoipCallState extends Call{

  public void notifyRegState(pjsip_status_code code, String reason, int expiration) {}
      log.i(Tag,reason);
}
```